# Swift - filter Realm objects via UISearchBar in a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uisearchbar, realm

This is my Realm object, basically an image with some tag attached.

```
class AllTags: Object {
dynamic var singleTag = ""}

class Photo: Object {
var myTags: [String] {

    get {
        return _backingNewTags.map { $0.singleTag }
    }
    set {
        _backingNewTags.removeAll()
        _backingNewTags.appendContentsOf(newValue.map({ AllTags(value: [$0]) }))
    }
}

let _backingNewTags = List<AllTags>()

override static func ignoredProperties() -> [String] {
    return ["myTags"]
}

dynamic var imagePath = ""}
```

I have my collectionView, I can see all my photo and when pressing an image I can see my tags, so everything is working correctly. 
I have added my UISearchBar, added the `txtSearchbar.delegate = self` and using `let data = realm.objects(AllTags).map { $0.singleTag }` I can print ALL the tags inside my database.

I just need to filter in real time while I type the CollectionView cells via the UISearchBar so it shows only the images tagged with the word I'm typing. Basic.

I've been following this tutorial to filter in the collectionView - https://github.com/codepath/ios_guides/wiki/Search-Bar-Guide#example-searching-a-collection-view - After 11 hours, I can't figure out how to make it works with Realm. With hardcoded Array like the example I can make it works.

Answer (score 1):

In Realm, you can filter a `Results<T>` based on what you're looking for. For example:

```
let data = realm.objects(AllTags).filter("singleTag CONTAINS %@", searchTerm)
```

I'm wondering, however, why you're converting your `_backingNewTags` to an Array `[String]`? Why can't you just access the tags directly? This will be much more memory & CPU efficient, and will simplify your code...

Comment: I'm pretty new to development, I took this code from a tutorial. I had problems creating an array of tags in Realm and this code at least worked. So where should I use the code you wrote? in the searchBar func? Right now I'm using a super complicated code to filter and is kinda working, but I'm sure there's an easier way to do it

Comment: yes, you'd apply the fetch for objects & filtering in your search bar delegate that's notified when the search string has changed, and in what I assume is a table view rendering the results, you'd get the count from the `Results<T>` and when getting `cellForRow...` you'd return the cell with its properties assigned from the Realm object at that index.